# Definition multiplication for fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[From book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IceLm.jpg) Elementary Algebra for Schools H.S. Hall

In an old textbook I saw this passage regarding multiplying fractions: "*When the quantities to be multiplied together are not positive whole numbers, we may define multiplication as **an operation performed on one quantity which when performed on unity produces the other***"

What does the bold part mean? Isn't unity 1?

So for example: $\frac{2}{3}$x$\frac{5}{7}$

$\frac{2}{3}$ would be "***one quantity***", then the statement "***which when performed on unity produces the other***" would mean $1$$x$$\frac{5}{7}$=$\frac{5}{7}$ ?

Which seems to be stating the obvious. I'm still not understanding what that statement means. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Welcome to **MSE**!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please add an screenshot or photo of the statement form the book

Comment: I added a screenshot from the book.

Comment: @asdasdwerwefsdfsdfsdf The screenshot shows a worked out example in the book with a step by step explanation. Which part of that do you have a difficulty with?

Comment: @dixv I know how to multiply fractions. I'm having a problem with understanding its definition of this operation: "an operation performed on one quantity which when performed on unity produces the other"

Comment: @asdasdwerwefsdfsdfsdf Not sure what answer you are looking for, other than someone maybe copy-pasting the explanation given in the book. If there is something in particular which you don't follow in *that* explanation, then ask about that part specifically.

Comment: @asdasdwerwefsdfsdfsdf That's not a productive comment. But you can delete your question if you don't want further activitiy on it.

Comment: @asdasdwerwefsdfsdfsdf No problem, that's entirely your call whether to improve the chances that your question may get a useful answer. And btw, that line of "joke" is not remotely funny to many nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Take your example: $$\frac{2}{3}\times \frac{5}{7}.$$ We'll call $2/3$ the "one quantity" and $5/7$ the "other quantity." The operation that is performed on $1$ that produces $5/7$ is simply dividing $1$ into $7$ equal parts and taking  $5$ of them.

When this operation is performed on $2/3$, that amounts to

Divide into $7$ equal parts: $$\frac{2}{3\times 7}$$
Take $5$ parts: $$\frac{2\times 5}{3\times 7}.$$

The above is also the explanation the book gives, just applied to your example. In summary, the book is saying

$$\frac{a}{b}\times \frac{c}{d}=\frac{a\times c}{b\times d}.$$